# Php code in href=" "

Tags: php, hyperlink, href

I would like to add PHP code inside a href="" , but my site crashed.
What I tried, I would like to check if inside site URL have string `'en'`  to change path inside `a href`, but with this my site crashed! This is inside wordpress but I think it's pure PHP.

```
<ul>
    <li><a href=
            <?php
                $url = 'http://' . $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];

                if (strpos($url,'en') !== false) {
                    echo ("en/about" );
                } elseif{
                    echo ("/o-nama" );
                } 
            ?>
        >
            <?php _e('About Distillery','all_custom_strings'); ?> 
        </a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make it simple like this:

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <?php
        $url = 'http://' . $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
        switch (true) {
            case strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], 'en') !== false:
                $action = '/en/about';
                break;
            case strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], 'ru') !== false:
                $action =  ''; // whatever you set for 'ru'
                break;
            default:
                $action =  '/o-nama';
        }
        ?>
        <a href="<?php echo $action; ?>">
            <?php _e('About Distillery','all_custom_strings'); ?> 
        </a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

In your code you have elseif without condition.

Comment: Works fine thanks, but what if I add another string to check for example I have next to "en" I have "ru" , and if inside URL have ru open this url.
On my site, I have english, russian language and default language serbian